# Is there a way to set compiler options inline with Typescript

Tags: typescript, compiler-construction

In my tsconfig I set `strictNullChecks` to true.

I just reported an issue with the `ProxyHandler.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` definition, which is improperly declared as returning a `PropertyDescriptor` where it should be `PropertyDescriptor | undefined`

I am trying to write my own ProxyHandler, and implement `getOwnPropertyDescriptor():PropertyDescriptor` (to fulfill the current contract in the type definition). But I cannot because the compiler reports an error when I try to cast my internal `PropertyDescriptor | undefined` result to `PropertyDescriptor`

```
getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target: T, p: PropertyKey): PropertyDescriptor {
    let res: PropertyDescriptor | undefined = undefined
    //... compute result
    return res as PropertyDescriptor; 
       // FAILS : [ts] Type 'undefined' cannot be converted to type 'PropertyDescriptor'.
}
```

Does anyone know a way to use special comments to disable strictNullChecks only inside my method (I want to preserve this check for all my other files) ?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9432. The point made here is that `strictNullChecks` is not something that even makes sense on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: Why don't you change the declaration of res so it can't be undefined, and remove the casting? If your implementation allows for an undefined state, then perhaps you should reconsider the type your method returns.